# Get Index of Object in TouchesEnded

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, uitouch

i have a UIViewController with many UIImageViews. I need in touchEnded event get a index of this UIimage.

How do Make?

Thank's

Answer (score 1):

make a custom `UIImageview` class which is subclass of `UIControl`. and add a target method for this class.set the tag  for each `UIImageview`. and change the class name of `UIImageview` in inspector window to that custom class.

```
[imageview addTarget: self action:@selector(findIndex:)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside ]
```

you can set this  method using xib also.
and define findIndex method in your viewController class.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of UIImageViews, why don't you use UIButtons? You can set the image with `setImage:forState:`, and the target action and object with `addTarget:action:forControlEvents`. When your target action gets called, the button will be sent as the `sender` argument.

Comment: Adam thanks for reply, but i need drag a Image ,can possible with UIButton?

Comment: Sure, you can drag any subclass of `UIView`. I would use a `UIPanGestureRecognizer` that adjusts the `frame` of the object you want to drag.

Comment: But if i use UIButton, i don't know x and y position to drag button because touches events occur after press button.